# Please help i got error on a null object reference. when i click confirm button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

My logcat here

- E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
         Process: com.example.barberbooking, PID: 13610
         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.barberbooking.Model.Salon.getSalonId()'
     on a null object reference
             at com.example.barberbooking.Fragments.BookingStep4Fragment.lambda$null$0$BookingStep4Fragment(BookingStep4Fragment.java:260)
             at com.example.barberbooking.Fragments.-$$Lambda$BookingStep4Fragment$4Ef790x-NNkmXHs_bv2YFCA2Nyk.onSuccess(Unknown
     Source:4)
             at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
             at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

---

My Bookingstep4fragment

package com.example.barberbooking.Fragments;

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;


import com.example.barberbooking.Common.Common;
import com.example.barberbooking.Database.CartDataSource;
import com.example.barberbooking.Database.CartDatabase;
import com.example.barberbooking.Database.CartItem;
import com.example.barberbooking.Database.LocalCartDataSource;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.BookingInformation;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.EventBus.ConfirmBookingEvent;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.FCMResponse;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.FCMsendData;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.MyNotification;
import com.example.barberbooking.Model.MyToken;
import com.example.barberbooking.R;
import com.example.barberbooking.Retrofit.IFCMApi;
import com.example.barberbooking.Retrofit.RetrofitClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.UUID;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Unbinder;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;
import io.paperdb.Paper;
import io.reactivex.SingleObserver;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class BookingStep4Fragment extends Fragment {

    CartDataSource cartDataSource;

    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;

    Unbinder unbinder;

    IFCMApi ifcmApi;

    AlertDialog dialog;

    @BindView(R.id.txt_booking_barber_text)
    TextView txt_booking_barber_text;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_booking_time_text)
    TextView txt_booking_time_text;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_salon_address)
    TextView txt_salon_address;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_salon_open_hours)
    TextView txt_salon_open_hours;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_salon_phone)
    TextView txt_salon_phone;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_salon_website)
    TextView txt_salon_website;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_salon_name)
    TextView txt_salon_name;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_confirm)
    void confirmBooking() {

        dialog.show();



        //DatabaseUtils.getAllCart(CartDatabase.getInstance(getContext()),
        //this);
        compositeDisposable.add(cartDataSource.getAllItemFromCart(Common.currentUser.getPhoneNumber())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<CartItem>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<CartItem> cartItems) throws Exception {


                        String startTime = Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot);
                        String[] convertTime = startTime.split("-"); 

                        String[] startTimeConvert = convertTime[0].split(":");
                        int startHourInt = Integer.parseInt(startTimeConvert[0].trim()); 
                        int startMinInt = Integer.parseInt(startTimeConvert[1].trim()); // We get 00

                        Calendar bookingDateWithourHouse = Calendar.getInstance();
                        bookingDateWithourHouse.setTimeInMillis(Common.currentDate.getTimeInMillis());
                        bookingDateWithourHouse.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHourInt);
                        bookingDateWithourHouse.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinInt);

                        //Create timestamp object and apply to BookingInformation
                        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(bookingDateWithourHouse.getTime());



                        final BookingInformation bookingInformation = new BookingInformation();

                        bookingInformation.setCityBook(Common.city);
                        bookingInformation.setTimestamp(timestamp);
                        bookingInformation.setDone(false); 
                        bookingInformation.setBarberId(Common.currentBarber.getBarberId());
                        bookingInformation.setBarberName(Common.currentBarber.getName());
                        bookingInformation.setCustomerName(Common.currentUser.getName());
                        bookingInformation.setCustomerPhone(Common.currentUser.getPhoneNumber());
                        bookingInformation.setSalonId(Common.currentSalon.getSalonId());
                        bookingInformation.setSalonAddress(Common.currentSalon.getAddress());
                        bookingInformation.setSalonName(Common.currentSalon.getName());
                        bookingInformation.setTime(new StringBuilder(Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot))
                                .append(" at ")
                                .append(simpleDateFormat.format(bookingDateWithourHouse.getTime())).toString());
                        bookingInformation.setSlot(Long.valueOf(Common.currentTimeSlot));
                        bookingInformation.setCartItemList(cartItems); 


                        DocumentReference bookingDate = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                .collection("AllSalon")
                                .document(Common.city)
                                .collection("Branch")
                                .document(Common.currentSalon.getSalonId())
                                .collection("Barber")
                                .document(Common.currentBarber.getBarberId())
                                .collection(Common.simpleDateFormat.format(Common.currentDate.getTime()))
                                .document(String.valueOf(Common.currentTimeSlot));


                        bookingDate.set(bookingInformation)
                                .addOnSuccessListener((aVoid) -> {

                                    resetStaticData();
                                    getActivity().finish(); activity
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    //DatabaseUtils.clearCart(CartDatabase.getInstance(getContext()));
                                    cartDataSource.clearCart(Common.currentUser.getPhoneNumber())
                                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                                                    addToUserBooking(bookingInformation);
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            });


                                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }));

    }

    private void addToUserBooking(BookingInformation bookingInformation) {



        final CollectionReference userBooking = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("User")
                .document(Common.currentUser.getPhoneNumber())
                .collection("Booking");


        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        Timestamp toDayTimeStamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTime());

        userBooking
                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timestamp", toDayTimeStamp)
                .whereEqualTo("done", false)
                .limit(1) 
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {

                        userBooking.document()
                                .set(bookingInformation)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {


                                    MyNotification myNotification = new MyNotification();
                                    myNotification.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                                    myNotification.setTitle("New Booking");
                                    myNotification.setContent("You have a new appoiment for customer hair care with " + Common.currentUser.getName());
                                    myNotification.setRead(false); // We will only filter notification with 'read' is false on barber staff app
                                    myNotification.setServerTimestamp(FieldValue.serverTimestamp());


                                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                            .collection("AllSalon")
                                            .document(Common.city)
                                            .collection("Branch")
                                            .document(Common.currentSalon.getSalonId())
                                            .collection("Barber")
                                            .document(Common.currentBarber.getBarberId())
                                            .collection("Notifications") 
                                            .document(myNotification.getUid()) 
                                            .set(myNotification)
                                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                                    //First , get Token base on Barber id
                                                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                                            .collection("Tokens")
                                                            .whereEqualTo("userPhone", Common.currentBarber.getUsername())
                                                            .limit(1)
                                                            .get()
                                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                                                @Override
                                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                                                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult().size() > 0) {
                                                                        MyToken myToken = new MyToken();
                                                                        for (DocumentSnapshot tokenSnapShot : task.getResult())
                                                                            myToken = tokenSnapShot.toObject(MyToken.class);


                                                                        FCMsendData sendRequest = new FCMsendData();
                                                                        Map<String, String> dataSend = new HashMap<>();
                                                                        dataSend.put(Common.TITLE_KEY, "New Booking");
                                                                        dataSend.put(Common.CONTENT_KEY, "You have new booking from user "+ Common.currentUser.getName());

                                                                        sendRequest.setTo(myToken.getToken());
                                                                        sendRequest.setData(dataSend);

                                                                        compositeDisposable.add(ifcmApi.sendNotification(sendRequest)
                                                                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                                                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                                                .subscribe(new Consumer<FCMResponse>() {
                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                    public void accept(FCMResponse fcmResponse) throws Exception {

                                                                                        dialog.dismiss();

                                                                                        addToCalendar(Common.currentDate,
                                                                                                Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot));
                                                                                        resetStaticData();
                                                                                        getActivity().finish(); //Close Activity
                                                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                                                    }
                                                                                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                                                                                    @Override
                                                                                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                                                                        Log.d("NOTIFICATION_ERROR", throwable.getMessage());
                                                                                        addToCalendar(Common.currentDate,
                                                                                                Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot));
                                                                                        resetStaticData();
                                                                                        getActivity().finish(); //Close Activity
                                                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }));

                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                }
                                            });


                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        if (dialog.isShowing())
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        if (dialog.isShowing())
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        resetStaticData();
                        getActivity().finish(); // Close activity
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void addToCalendar(Calendar bookingDate, String startDate) {
        String startTime = Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot);
        String[] convertTime = startTime.split("-"); //Split ex : 9:00-10:00
        //Get start time : get 9:00
        String[] startTimeConvert = convertTime[0].split(":");
        int startHourInt = Integer.parseInt(startTimeConvert[0].trim());            int startMinInt = Integer.parseInt(startTimeConvert[1].trim());

        String[] endTimeConvert = convertTime[1].split(":");
        int endHourInt = Integer.parseInt(endTimeConvert[0].trim()); 
        int endMinInt = Integer.parseInt(endTimeConvert[1].trim()); 

        Calendar startEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
        startEvent.setTimeInMillis(bookingDate.getTimeInMillis());
        startEvent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHourInt); 
        startEvent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinInt); 

        Calendar endEvent = Calendar.getInstance();
        endEvent.setTimeInMillis(bookingDate.getTimeInMillis());
        endEvent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endHourInt); hour
        endEvent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, endMinInt); 


        SimpleDateFormat calendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

        String startEventTime = calendarDateFormat.format(startEvent.getTime());
        String endEventTime = calendarDateFormat.format(endEvent.getTime());

        addToDeviceCalendar(startEventTime, endEventTime, "Haircut Booking",
                new StringBuilder("Haircut from ")
                        .append(startTime)
                        .append(" with ")
                        .append(Common.currentBarber.getName())
                        .append(" at ")
                        .append(Common.currentSalon.getName()).toString(),
                new StringBuilder("Address: ").append(Common.currentSalon.getAddress()).toString());
    }

    private void addToDeviceCalendar(String startEventTime, String endEventTime, String title, String description, String location) {
        SimpleDateFormat calendarDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

        try {
            Date start = calendarDateFormat.parse(startEventTime);
            Date end = calendarDateFormat.parse(endEventTime);

            ContentValues event = new ContentValues();



            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, getCalendar(getContext()));
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location);


            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, start.getTime());
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, end.getTime());
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, 0);
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

            String timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
            event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);

            Uri calendars;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22)
                calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
            else
                calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
            Uri uri_save = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(calendars, event);

            Paper.init(getActivity());
            Paper.book().write(Common.EVENT_URI_CACHE, uri_save.toString());


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private String getCalendar(Context context) {

        String gmailIdCalendar = "";
        String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);
        if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String calName;
            int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
            int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            do {
                calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
                if (calName.contains("@gmail.com")) {
                    gmailIdCalendar = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
                    break; // Exit as soon as have io
                }
            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
            managedCursor.close();
        }


        return gmailIdCalendar;
    }

    private void resetStaticData() {
        Common.step = 0;
        Common.currentTimeSlot = -1;
        Common.currentSalon = null;
        Common.currentBarber = null;
        Common.currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);//Current date
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void setDataBooking(ConfirmBookingEvent event) {
        if (event.isConfirm()) {
            setData();
        }
    }



    private void setData() {
        txt_booking_barber_text.setText(Common.currentBarber.getName());
        txt_booking_time_text.setText(new StringBuilder(Common.convertTimeSlotToString(Common.currentTimeSlot))
                .append(" at ")
                .append(simpleDateFormat.format(Common.currentDate.getTime())));

        txt_salon_address.setText(Common.currentSalon.getAddress());
        txt_salon_website.setText(Common.currentSalon.getWebsite());
        txt_salon_name.setText(Common.currentSalon.getName());
        txt_salon_open_hours.setText(Common.currentSalon.getOpenHours());
    }


    static BookingStep4Fragment instance;
    public static BookingStep4Fragment getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) ;
            instance = new BookingStep4Fragment();
        return instance;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ifcmApi = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(IFCMApi.class);

        //Apply format for date display on Confirm
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");


        dialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(getContext()).setCancelable(false)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        compositeDisposable.clear();
        super.onDestroy();
        { if (dialog != null) { dialog.dismiss(); dialog = null; }}
    }



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookingstep_four, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);


        cartDataSource = new LocalCartDataSource(CartDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).cartDAO());

        return itemView;

    }


}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Please try to make your content more clearer. Try to use code blocks properly so that your question will be easily understandable. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Check those lines

```
bookingInformation.setSalonId(Common.currentSalon.getSalonId());

.document(Common.currentSalon.getSalonId())
```

The error is clear

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.barberbooking.Model.Salon.getSalonId()' on a null object
```

You are sending `salonId null`

Comment: i can't understand those lines

Comment: mmm check if you have a value for "Common.currentSalon.getSalonId()", before those lines set some logs

Comment: Thank sir. My problem sloved

Comment: Happy to help ;)